# What is the best way to add a video upload button to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What combination of services can I use to add a video upload button to my website so I can them embed them on said website.

Comment: That question cannot be answered easily. There is lot of work to do to handle the uploading, storing and providing in the backend.

Comment: This question is way too broad, but as an overview you'll want to research how you're going to store the files on the server (formats, size limits, etc), how you plan on serving the files to users, and how the users are going to send their files from the frontend to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading a video you need to find a service that suits you (YouTube, Vimeo...). This will involve some research and reading through the documentations.

Embedding the video to the website you can use the iframe tag

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="your video url" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```